# In which cases should parameters be pinned when performing a P/Invoke call

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I have a DLL from which I need to P/Invoke the following C method:

```
int DAOpen(HANDLE *hOpen, UNIT *flags, void *callback, char *userData)
```

I've come up with the following C# signature:

```
[DllImportAttribute("<libName>", EntryPoint="DAOpen")]  
    static extern  int DAOpen(  
    out IntPtr hOpen,  
    ref uint flags,  
    IntPtr callback,  
    IntPtr userData);
```

Assuming the native code keeps a reference to all parameters for longer than the duration of the P/Invoke call:

1. Aside from keeping an instance of the `hOpen`, should I also pin it?
2. Should I keep a reference of the `flags` variable? Should I also pin it since it's passed as a reference in this particular case?
3. I'm assigning my `callback` delegate in the following way:

   `private IntPtr callBackOnNativeEvents;`
   `...`
   `this.callBackOnNativeEvents = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(`
   `new CallBack(this.CallBackOnNativeEvents));`

   Should I keep a reference to the delegate in itself (not only the pointer)? Should I also pin it?
4. Finally, I'm defining the `userData` parameter in the following way:

   `private IntPtr userData;`
   `...`
   `string userName = "test";`
   `this.userData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(userName);`

   Should I keep a reference to the string? Should I also pin it? The API documentation states that it copies the string content to unmanaged memory, but I'm not sure if it copies the content of the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No need to pin `hOpen`, it has value type semantics.
2. If the DLL writes to the address pointed to by `flags`, and does so after the original function returns, then you need to pin it one way or another (as well as keeping it alive and safe from the clutches of the GC).
3. The callback function pointer is already effectively pinned. You need to keep a reference to the delegate alive, but you don't need to pin it because the [native thunk is allocated from the unmanged heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164193.aspx#S7).
4. You don't need to do anything special here because you are passing an `IntPtr` and the memory behind that is pinned. You don't need to to keep a reference to the string alive because it is completely disconnected from the `IntPtr` returned by `StringToHGlobalAnsi`. It just has a copy of the contents of the string at the point of call to `StringToHGlobalAnsi`.

I have to say that I am still incredulous that this DLL really could be doing what you say it is doing. I suspect that something else is going wrong which you are mis-diagnosing as the DLL holding onto pointer parameters from one call and then modifying their contents during subsequent calls. I find that exceptionally hard to believe, but of course only you can really know. If I was in your position I would simply ask the question of the DLL vendor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Exactly what  I was lookin for. I will contact them because this is indeed bad form. However, this would not surprise me since they keep a reference to everything in their example code (C++) for the full duration of the application.

Comment: Concerning point #3, I'm a bit puzzled... Won't the delegate be garbage collected since I'm not keeping a reference to it?

Comment: I'm keeping an `IntPtr` pointing to it, but not the delegate function per se. I'm using `new` to create it on the fly as a parameter to the `GetFunctionPointerForDelegate` function.

Comment: @XenoAce You will need to keep the delegate alive, but you don't need to worry about pinning. I've added a link in item 3 to clarify that point.

Comment: Ah, this is what I thought... Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: Concerning #4, if the native code modifies the `string` to a longer string, won't it cause overflow problems?

Comment: That would be a bug in the native code. How could the native code know how big the buffer was? Does you documentation place any requirement on buffer size? I think you are being unduly defensive here. You really can't program to an interface when you are second guessing what the rules are. You need to know the rules.

Comment: I've seen my string change from one to another, so I assume the native code only writes to whatever `char*` it gets, assuming that the API user has allowed enough memory (they do that all the time).

Comment: I still don't believe that. What do you mean "I've seen my string change from one to another"? And as for "I assume the native code only writes to whatever `char*` it gets" well, if that's what you believe then you've already answered the question you asked. The native code won't write beyond the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for not believing that, I've found the issue which was a mistake on my part, just as you said I was... It was a subtle one but I found it.

Comment: Good. I'm glad my persistent disbelief has helped give you strength to get to the bottom of this!